# Other conda environments do not automatically activate in VScode git bash

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, conda

I'm not really understanding what's happening with git bash and scripts in general. I'm just following a data science course and I'm trying to setup my environment nicely.

I first downloaded Anaconda3 and git bash. I'm also using git bash as my default terminal in VSCode.

I have 2 issues that are happening that are kinda of annoying.

When I start VS code, terminal (git bash) opens by default but does NOT activate conda. However, when I open a new terminal then it'll automatically "conda activate". I'm confused why it doesn't run it by default and I'm also confused why it runs it automatically when I open a new terminal session.

My other issue is that when I created a new conda environment called "pandas", for some reason this breaks that script that automatically activates the environment. As in that scripts works perfectly when I'm using the default conda interpreter "base" but if I change it, it'll just give me this error message when I open a new terminal.

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate pandas
>
> bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3Scriptsactivate: command not found

if I manually type in "conda activate pandas" it'll work.

Comment: "Git bash" has nothing to do with Git. It's a port of bash to Windows, that exists because Git *needs* a POSIX-ish shell, and bash is a POSIX-ish shell. But it has nothing to do with Git, it's just supplied *along with* Git when you get Git-for-Windows.

Comment: Note that backslashes in Unix style shells mean "quote the next character". You have to type in `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate` to use backslashes. This is pretty annoying, but fortunately you can use *forward* slashes instead: `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate`, for instance.

Comment: I don't know why, off-hand, you're getting activation in some shells and not in others; I don't use Windows and this seems like one of those special Windows "features".